# Morphia: can two objects pull from the same collection if one is a subset of the other?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

Lets say I have two very basic classes that share most of their information that I want to store in mongo.  Like this:

```
public class Customer{

    @id
    private int customerID;
    private String Name;
    private int social;
    private long balance;
}


public class CustomerInfo{

    @id
    private int customerID;
    private String Name;
    private int social;
    private long balance;
    private Address address;
    private PhoneNumber phoneNumber;
}
```

If I don't want to have two nearly-identical collections when one should do.  Can I create a single collection for `CustomerInfo` and still populate the `Customer` class with the records contained inside, since they are a subset of `CustomerInfo`?

I know I can load `customerInfo` with only the values I care about, but I would like something that is a little more elegant, and which plugs into my existing format better.

Comment: Why not give it a try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Entity(value="customers", noClassnameStored=false)
public class Customer {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    private String Name;
    private int social;
    private long balance;
}


public class CustomerInfo extends Customer {
    private Address address;
    private PhoneNumber phoneNumber;
}
```

It should work like that. Since you are storing the class name in each document, you can easily query for the one you want to use; even though Morphia would figure this out on its own based on the attributes.

PS: And unless you know what and why you are doing it, keep your ID an ObjectId.
PPS: You might want to use object data types instead of primitives in case they can be empty — in which case they won't be stored and use up space in in your database.